# $x^3-8x^2+30x-20=0$ has roots $a$, $b$, $c$. Find the equation with roots $a+2$, $b+2$, $c+2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations

I have the equation $$x^3-8x^2+30x-20=0$$ let's call the roots $a,b,c$

It's easy to find the equation with roots $(a+2)(b+2)(c+2)$
these are the steps in my books

[image]

so the equation is $$ aX^3+ bX^2 + cX + D = 0 $$
$$ x^3 -14x^2 +74x -120 = 0$$

my problem is, I can't understand why divide by $-2$ not $2$
how do I do this division with long division? like what am I dividing by if the symbols were here?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are finding $P(x-2)$, given $P(x)$. If $a$ is a root of $P(x)$, clearly $a+2$ is a root of $P(x-2)$.

Comment: well, I'm disappointed in my self but it's not 'clearly' for me, I'll be thankful if you provide a more detailed answer

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed Just replace $x$ in $P(x-2)$ with $a+2$, you will get $P(a)$, which is zero if $a$ is a root of $P(x)$.  Try it and let me know if there is some confusion.

Comment: Well, if $P(x)=0$, for $P((x+2))=0$, then it must be $P((x+2)-2)$, for $(x+2)-2=x$.

Comment: Thanks, this will be appreciated

Comment: +1. Could you extend your answer to $(a+1)(b+2)(c+3)$?

Comment: @farruhota that isn’t symmetric in $a, b, c$, so the roots you intend are ambiguous.  For e.g. the possible roots could be $a+1, a+2, a+3, b+1, b+2, b+3, ...$ depending on what you consider is $a, b, c$ from among the three roots of $P(x)$,  leading to potentially a $9$th degree polynomial, which is of course easily $P(x-1)P(x-2)P(x-3)$.

Comment: Yes, that is why I am asking. Say $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)=x^3-6x^2+11x-6=0$ with roots $a=1,b=2,c=3$. Find the equation with roots $a+1,b+2,c+3$, (which is $(x-2)(x-4)(x-6)=x^3-12x^2+44x-48=0$), in general.

Comment: @farruhota If you specify $a=1, b=2, c=3$ then there is no ambiguity, and it is trivially $(x-a-1)(x-b-2)(x-c-3)$ for the known $a, b, c$.  However if you just say given $a, b, c$ are roots of $x^3-6x^2+11x-6$, find the polynomial with roots $a+1, b+2, c+3$, it is ambiguous and not a well defined problem, as it is unclear which is $a, b, c$.  If you think you can make a well defined problem out of this, please post separately, will be glad to respond.

Comment: are you saying the synthetic divison will not work in this case?

Comment: I am saying the problem isn’t well defined in “this” case.  If the transformation is symmetric, the ordering of $a, b, c$ is immaterial and you have a well defined problem.  If the transformation of roots is not symmetric, then the ordering matters, and you need to specify what is $a$, what is $b$ etc., which is then a trivial problem,  If you don’t specify which is $a, b, c$ in the asymmetric case, the problem is NOT well defined, in the sense it does not have a unique cubic as an answer.

Comment: OK, I see, referring to my answer below (where the symmetry helped), the method will not work for $(a+1)(b+2)(c+3)$ unless $a,b,c$ are found first. Thank you.

Comment: If you are interested in this method, check https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_transformation for more transformations, which can be composed to address more complex cases.

Comment: Thank you for discussion and the reference.

Answer (score 4):

Your book is using synthetic division. As you are dividing by $(x+2)$, the divisor must be $-2$. Generalized, if you are dividing polynomial $f(x)$ by $x+a$, for synthetic division, you use $-a$, which is exactly what your book did.

Comment: surely i understand that, I got it anyway thanks

Comment: As Quote Dave mentions, you are actually evaluation $P(-2)$ say to get the constant coefficient, which is the same as finding the remainder when you divide by $x+2$, which is the first synthetic division step you do in the diagram.  Similarly from the quotient, you extract the next remainder, which is the coefficient of the linear term and so on.  +1

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively: for the roots $a,b,c$ of $x^3-8x^2+30x-20=0$, by Vieta's we have:
$$a+b+c=8\\
ab+bc+ca=30\\
abc=20$$
Now we want the roots $a+2,b+2,c+2$ of $X^3+kX^2+lX+m=0$. Hence:
$$a+2+b+2+c+2=a+b+c+6=14=-k\\
(a+2)(b+2)+(b+2)(c+2)+(c+2)(a+2)=\\
(ab+bc+ca)+4(a+b+c)+12=74=l\\
(a+2)(b+2)(c+2)=\\
abc+2(ab+bc+ca)+4(a+b+c)+8=120=-m \Rightarrow \\
x^3-14x^2+74x-120=0.$$

Comment: Vieta approach is more generic and works for symmetric polynomial transformations +1

Comment: Thank you, that is what I observed.

Comment: Awesome approach thanks

Comment: but tbh, it's not practical it will take a year to do this for a 4th or 5th degree equation

Comment: Yes, you are right. Also as conmented above it will work for symmetric polynomial, i.e. it will not work when roots are $2,3,4$, etc. Anyway, it is a valid and guaranteed method.